# Will this battery to USB auto switching circuit work?

Tags: mosfet, power, batteries, usb

I want to have a project be powered by six AA batteries or USB. When the USB cable is attached the circuit should automatically switch off the battery input and start using 5 V from the USB.

This is the circuit I've come up with by copying component setups from the Arduino Uno R3 and an Adafruit Feather,  the idea here being that when the USB power is connected it applies voltage to the MOSFET that then disconnects the battery from the voltage regulator.

The Zener diode that goes between the USB voltage input and the voltage regulator output protects the USB from backfeed. In total my entire circuit that this supplies power to will use less than 500 mA.

My understanding is that it is typically not recommended to have another voltage input attached to the output of a voltage regulator without a protection diode, but I assume if the Arduino has gotten away with it then maybe it will work in this case and save me a component as well as the voltage drop over that diode.

If, however, I do need a diode there, what would be a good one to use?

[image]

Comment: I'd say no, look at the FET internal diode feeding battery supply always to regulator because it is larger than 5V. Also if you plug that in to USB, the 47uF capacitor likely exceeds the surge current energy limit. But what is a DMG341, I could not find any data sheet with that specific part number.

Comment: @Justme it's probably 3415 because 341 is a series name i.e. 3414 is NMOS, 3415 is PMOS etc.

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly what the DMG341 is myself. It makes sense now why this wouldn't work as the circuit I was copying was providing 3.7v from a Lipo Battery. Thank you for clearing that up, I'm definitely learning from this!
PS: I was basing it off the Adafruit 328P Feather's power section 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hurLQ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the USB cable is attached the circuit should automatically switch off the battery input and start using 5 V from the USB.

Your circuit will not work like that.

When `VIN` is available, regardless of whether `VUSB` is available or not, the 5V regulator will see `VIN` through the PMOS DMG341 (either its body diode or its "on" resistance, R<sub>DS-on</sub>) as per the connection shown:

- When `VUSB` is unavailable whilst `VIN` is available, the PMOS will be on so the regulator will see `VIN`.
- When `VUSB` is available whilst `VIN` is available, the PMOS will be off but the regulator will see `VIN` **through the PMOS's body diode**.

> The Zener diode that goes between the USB voltage input and the voltage regulator output

It's not a Zener diode, it's a Schottky barrier diode.

> My understanding is that it is typically not recommended to have another voltage input attached to the output of a voltage regulator without a protection diode

I don't know the 1117's design but I personally wouldn't apply an external voltage across a regulator's output, regardless of whether through a diode or directly. If 1117's series pass element is a PNP transistor (I really don't know, I just assumed so), for example, which means the output is taken from the collector, then the external voltage applied across the output will simply forward bias the CB junction when the regulator is off (i.e. no input). This may or may not result in an IC failure, I don't know. If you want to have the regulator output and the `VUSB` OR'ed then the simplest way is to connect them with OR'ing diodes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbiZgw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> ... but I assume if the Arduino has gotten away with it then maybe it will work in this case and save me a component as well as the voltage drop over that diode.

I've just checked the [R3's schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf). When there's no power applied from the power input connector shown as X1<sup>*why would a designer name a connector with X anyway?*</sup>, the `USBVCC` (USB 5V) will pass through T1 PMOS (FDN340P) body diode <sup>**1**</sup> and power LP2985 to generate 3.3V, also will be used as `+5V` for the rest of the circuit. Now the potential problem here is that the `USBVCC` might be supplying current into the regulator's output when the regulator is off. If this usage is allowed by the design/designer then that's fine, but I wouldn't do that.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The T1 is simply there just as a reverse-polarity protection. If the main intention is the disconnect the `USBVCC` when a DC input is available then simply it won't work like that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, this is helping me learn about things I didn't know that I didn't know. I was basing the battery switching part of the circuit on [something that was using a 3.7v lipo battery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hurLQ.pngi.stack.imgur.com/hurLQ.png) and not 9v. It makes sense now why that wouldn't work. 

This is the first time I've heard of OR'ing diodes and I'll need to do some reading to better understand the concept. I do have some initial questions in regards to the circuit you illustrated but I think I'll start a new question thread. 

Thanks again.